# I recieve and error in turtle module in python saying: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'bg'

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

The Simple Python Programme which is supposed to open a window with black background shows the error.

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Turtle by Lord Hendrix")
wn.bg('Black')
wn.setup(width=1000, height=800)
wn.tracer(0)
```

The Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lord_hendrix17/PycharmProjects/Game Dev/Game1.py", line 7, in <module>
    wn.bg('Black')
AttributeError: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'bg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wn.bgcolor('Black')
```

This correction did the job